# updates to Linux Mint 16

Tags: debian

Just installed Linux Mint 16 a few days ago. I am now on the internet from it and the first thing I did was try to get all the updates installed. It came right back with some error messages that it could not find http://security.ubuntu.com/dists/sauch-security/main/binary-i386/packages. As a result it does some things but right away the little icon in the bottom right of my screen (the shield) has an X in it indicating that I am not yet up to date.

I can go to the web site http://security.ubuntu.com/dists but there really isn't anything there that looks like the next level down. Can someone help me find the updates I need and just teach me how to tell the update manager on my machine which path to follow in the future?

Thanks a MILLION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mint 16 is already 1.5 years old. Please install the latest version 17.3 from the official site http://linuxmint.com

Comment: For a newbie, I really liked the step by step instructions on http://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-linux-mint-16-to-linux-mint-17/

Comment: However after the installation and during the reboot it gave me some ominous sounding error messages on a blank black screen down the right side. Then the "desktop" came up but the mouse can't be moved. So I can't DO anything. Is there some help please? Otherwise I just created a good doorstop.